express middleware connect-timeout not terminating the operation even after a timeout and sending 503 response
I have an express application with long-running operations, I want to stop the operation when the timeout is hit or a timeout event is emitted.
So when I stop the operation, do I have to close all the different types of database connections, Kafka connections etc (we do have the sigterm and the sigint hooks that gracefully shut down the connections) or should we do something on req level by calling req.destroy, req.close or req.timedout?
How can I do this we have requests running for 47 minutes and I want to do it safely such that it doesn't affect other requests coming through since, we have thousands of requests coming in a second, and want to terminate long-running processes without affecting the server as well.
For reference, we run an express server using pm2 with max instances on 16 core CPUs.
The issue that I am facing is the timeouts itself which are affecting the server's health. These timeouts is affecting new request by blocking thread causing them to timeout as well.
How can I make sure that I terminate this long-running operation after request timed out
Following is POC the long running operation.
(In my case I have a function with exponential backoff retries, which keeps sending message until it succeed)
const express = require("express");
const timeout = require("connect-timeout");

const app = express();

// Set a global timeout of 3 seconds
app.use(timeout("3s"));

app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This route responds quickly");
});

app.get("/long-operation", (req, res) => {
  let counter = 0;
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    counter++;
    console.log(`Operation still running: ${counter}`);
    if (counter === 15) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      res.send(`Operation completed after ${counter} seconds`);
    }
  }, 1000);
});

const PORT = 5500;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});


Your code doesn't explain the exact problem you face. What is the "Problem" here?

Generally, each request has its scope and life cycle in express JS. So it doesn't affect another request unless you didn't handle the error properly which could crash the server. You shouldn't terminate database connections when terminating requests. Creating a database connection is expensive, so it should be pooled. Do not open and terminate connections for each request.

Your request to start the long running process, can start and continue the process in the background and return a process/job id. You can use this job/process id for further monitoring the process status and/or to terminate  the process. - thru another request.

i don't understand hou your request runs for 47 min as in my knowledge nodejs default timeout is 2 min. Even though if you have increased it, there is no point as this kind of long running tasks must be run in separate process as those cloud block event loop. So this dowsnt look like efficient code.

@BadPiggie the example, is the POC of a long running operation. The issue that I am facing is the timeouts itself which are affecting the server's health (Updated the question)
These timeouts is affecting new request by blocking thread causing them to timeout as well

@prasad_ In my case I have a function with exponential backoff retries, which keeps sending message until it succeed (Update the question)

@BrijeshDave ^^

maybe you should rephrase/narrow your question: is it that you want to do it with connect timeout, or how to do it in general? regarding connect timeout, why not use it on route level instead of top level in your PoC (see example (and then "catch" timeout and implement shutdown services, or pass it to error handler..)
